# Mod Python not working

Tags: python, mod-python, ganglia, centos6.5

I have installed `mod_python-3.3.1-16.el6.x86_64` using `epel` repository in `Centos 6.5` for Ganglia Python Modules.

When I start gmond service, I am getting the following error:

> Starting GANGLIA gmond: Cannot load /usr/lib64/ganglia/mod_python.so metric module: /usr/lib64/ganglia/mod_python.so: undefined symbol: ap_my_generation

Is there any workaround for this?